# HOWTO get transaction receipts for Google Play In-App Subscriptions via Google Play Developer API

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-billing, google-api-java-client

We have a subscription service that our users can directly subscribe to via Web. But now we are also launching an Android App with enabled Google Play In-App Subscriptions.

So users can subscribe via directly their Android App. Now we need to keep track of this in our backend, so that when users come to the web they should be able to log in & enjoy the content they have subscribed to.

To track whether a user is subscribed or not is fairly trivial by using the [Purchases.subscriptions.get()](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get) method.

But we also provide a billing history to the users (which is used in other contexts). Basically we need to know when was a user actually charged for their monthly/yearly dues. On a recurring basis from our backend servers using the Google Play API client.

My question is, how to get this information? Is it possible to get it via the Play Developer API?

Answer (score 0):

***The getSkuDetails() method*** will enable you to do what you intent to do what you wish to do. This method would return the following *productId, type (will return **subs** in this case as yours is a subscription), price, price_amount_micros, price_currency_code, title, description*.

For more details read the official documentation on [The getSkuDetails() method](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getSkuDetails).

Comment: Thanks @AniV for the response. But I think this method can be called form the App using Android SDK and not from my backend server using the Java API for Play Developer APi. I can not trust this mechanism since it is possible that the app might not be working periodically or might be uninstalled but the subscription might still be working.

Comment: I dont see any way to get the data as of now. However you can get data using a Purchases.subscriptions call and cancel, defer, get, refund or revoke requests. https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. There are no documented ways. However i was hoping for a workaround.

Comment: I sort of missed that aspect where you wanted to retrieve billing related data through web and not android. A workaround would be to send the data obtained on the mobile device to the server. But that would be a lot of work, hopefully someone can comeup with a better one :)

Comment: Have any of you tried: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get not sure if it would show subs however, still testing

Comment: So far, the only way I have been able to do this is by configuring the pub/sub webhook and calling this endpoint using the purchaseToken: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/get

Since the webhook is called everytime a subscription is renewed, you can grate a register in your backend to keep track of renewals and amounts.